# Next.js: getStaticPaths for nested dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, static-site-generation

Imagine you have this data structure:

```js
const data = {
  posts: [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Post 1"
    slug: "post-1"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    title: "Post 2"
    slug: "post-2"
  }],

  comments: [{
    id: 1,
    postId: "post-1",
    text: "Comment 1 for Post 1"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    postId: "post-1",
    text: "Comment 2 for Post 1"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    postId: "post-2",
    text: "Comment 1 for Post 2"
  }]
}
```

An you have the following route `/posts/[postId[/[commentId]`
so the Next.js structure folder is: `posts/[postId]/[commented].js`

Then you need to generate the static paths for this routes.

I'm coded the following:

```js
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { posts, comments } = data
  const paths = posts.map((post) => {
    return comments
      .filter((comment) => comment.postId === post.slug)
      .map((comment) => {
        return {
          params: {
            postId: post.slug,
            commentId: comment.id
          }
        }
      })
  })
}
```

But it's not working. The throwed error was:

```
Error: Additional keys were returned from `getStaticPaths` in page "/clases/[courseId]/[lessonId]". URL Parameters intended for this dynamic route must be nested under the `params` key, i.e.:

        return { params: { postId: ..., commentId: ... } }

Keys that need to be moved: 0, 1.
```

How I can "map" or "loop" the data to a proper returned format?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your returning this from `getStaticPaths` data with a wrong shape:

```
[
  [ { params: {} }, { params: {} } ],
  [ { params: {} } ]
]
```

The correct shape is:

```
[
  { params: {} },
  { params: {} },
  { params: {} }
]
```

Just tried this and it works.

```
    export async function getStaticPaths() {
      const paths = data.comments.map((comment) => {
        return {
          params: {
            postId: comment.postId,
            commentId: comment.id
          }
        }
      });
    
      console.log(paths);
    
      return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
      }
    };
```

It generates 3 urls:

- /posts/post-1/1
- /posts/post-1/2
- /posts/post-2/3

Is that what you need?

Comment: Thx @Aaron! You have made me see that by double mapping the arrays for nothing. I already had in "comment" the id of the "post"!

Comment: I had an issue with the params , later I realised that in the params key/value , the value should be converted to string. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Like mention @Aaron the problem is for double array of filter y el map.

```
 return {
    paths: [
        { params: { id: '1' } },
        { params: { id: '2' } }
      ],
      fallback: ...
}
```

Doc  ➡ https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#the-paths-key-required